# Java compare elements from an array in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to compare input with values in an arraylist.

```
public compare(number)
```

Ex;
I have an arraylist:

```
[100,1102,14051,1024, / 142,1450,15121,1482,/ 141,1912,14924,1001] // the / represents each entry
```

Each index of the array represents a unique attribute in my program. e.g index 0 represents `user id`, index 1 represents `room number` etc.
If I do `arraylist.get(2)` it returns the second array `(142,1450,15121,1482)`.

I'm trying to compare `number` to the 2nd element in each array.
So say I run this `compare(1102)`, I want it to iterate through each [1] in each array, and return true if there is a match at that index.

So I want it to compare the 'number' (1102) with each 1st index element `(1102,1450,1912)` and because 1102 is in the arraylist, return true

I've been searching around and couldn't find how to implement this, or word the question in the right way

Comment: what exactly are you stuck on? are you having trouble getting the list of the users from the main list?

Comment: I'm confused on how to access each element in the arraylist. If I get(0) it returns the whole first list. How can I access individual elements in the arraylist?

Comment: sorry for replying so late. Since `arraylist.get(0)` gives you an `ArrayList`, you can then use another `get()` to access the individual element (e.g. `arraylist.get(0).get(0)` will give you the first element of the first list)

Answer (score 1):

The Stream API can accomplish this.

```
public class MyCompare 
{
    private static Optional<Integer> compare(Integer valueToCompare)
    {
        Optional<Integer[]> matchingArray = listToCompare.stream()
                .filter(eachArray -> eachArray[1].equals(valueToCompare))
                .findFirst();

        if(matchingArray.isPresent())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < listToCompare.size(); i++)
            {
                if(listToCompare.get(i).equals(matchingArray.get()))
                {
                    return Optional.of(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private static List<Integer[]> listToCompare = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        listToCompare.add(new Integer[] { 100, 1102, 14051, 1024 });
        listToCompare.add(new Integer[] { 142, 1450, 15121, 1482 });
        listToCompare.add(new Integer[] { 141, 1912, 14924, 1001 });

        Optional<Integer> listIndex = compare(1102);
        if(listIndex.isPresent())
        {
            System.out.println("Match found in list index " + listIndex.get());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No match found");
        }
    }
}
```

Match found in list index 0

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way is to use an enhanced for-loop:

```
for (int[] items : list) {
    // do your checking in here
}
```

The somewhat more advanced, but much more elegant way would be to use streams:

```
list.stream()       // converts the list into a Stream.
    .flatMap(...)   // can map each array in the list to its nth element.
    .anyMatch(...); // returns true if any value in the stream matches the Predicate passed.
```

Stream API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your list and compare every second element:

```
public static boolean compare (int number){
    for( int i = 0; i<arraylist.size(); i++){
         if(number == arraylist.get(i)[1]){
            return true;
          }
     }
    return false;
 }
```